# Why might this answer to a differential question be false? Is there a more rigorous proof or counterexample?

Tags: solution-verification

I'm trepidatious to accept an answer here because there's a couple points the author hasn't cleared up

[Why doesn't this differential technique work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394466/why-doesnt-this-differential-technique-work)

$y''/y$ certainly exists if the solution exists wherever $y \neq 0$, and it is integrable.

Secondly, $y''/y = t$ which is an invertible function. In the worst case scenario, suppose we define a new function, the inverse Airy function's derivative over a compact set $Ai'^{-1}(t).$

We can represent $t$ then as $Ai'^{-1}(Ai'(t)) = t$ over varying compact intervals corresponding to the appropriate branch of its inverse, so clearly an antiderivative does exist in terms of $y',$ though it is then still an open-question as to how we derive it.

What are the flaws in our reasonings here?

Comment: You want to integrate $y''/y$ to get a solution of $y''=ty$ ?

Comment: It would be interesting to know if there was a concise way to integrate $y'' / y$ to obtain a differential relationship in terms of $y$ and $y'.$

Answer (score 1):

In a nice answer to the post you are referring to it was demonstrated that $y''/y$ is not the first derivative of a function $f(y,y')\,.$ That's the reason we can't separate variables when we solve the ODE $y''=y\,g(x)\,.$

This is maybe not the end of the world. Apparently,
$$
\frac{y''}{y}-\frac{y'^2}{y^2}
$$
is the second derivative of the function $f(y)=\log y\,.$ More generally, for arbitrary twice differentialbe $f\,,$
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(y)=f'(y)\,y'\,,\quad\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(y)=f'(y)\,y''+f''(y)\,y'^2\,.
$$
When $f$ is invertible this means that the ODE
\begin{align}\tag{1}
f'(y)\,y'&=g(x)\,,\\[3mm]
\end{align}
has the solution
\begin{align}
\textstyle y=f^{-1}\Big(\int_0^x g(z)\,dz\Big)+\Big(y(0)-f^{-1}(0)\Big)\,.
\end{align}
For the ODE
\begin{align}
f'(y)\,y''+f''(y)\,y'^2&=g(x)\tag{2}
\end{align}
we get first
$$
f'(y)\,y'=\textstyle\int g(x)\,dx=:h(x)
$$
which is an ODE of the form (1) and has a known solution.

I believe the old Book *Differntialgeleichungen* by E. Kamke (not sure if it was ever translated) is a good reference for such "non ordinary" ODEs.

Comment: Okay, so you've introduced this notion of "separable," what does that mean in an ODE? Because if you construct arbitrary special functions, you could always rearrange an equation to isolate $y$ or $y'.$ $y'' = g(x)y$ looks separable to me, but you're saying the integral of this expression is some type of non-separable combination of $y'$ and some $\int g(x)$?

Comment: Also, $\int y'' / y = \frac{1}{2} t^2$ (or $\frac{1}{2} x^2$ in your case). If you define a special function $Ai'^{-1}(t),$ you can represent this integral as $Ai'^{-1}(Ai'(t))^2,$ so it appears to me there does exist an explicit expression in terms of $y'.$

Comment: Okay, separable doesn't seem like a huge deal. So, what if I don't care whether the integral of $y''/y$ is separable in terms of $y'$ and $y,$ but simply exists in some closed form in terms of $y'$ and $y$ and $t$ (or $x$)? It could be the least separable thing you can imagine like $\int \Gamma(y^{y'} - log_{y}(y'))$ or etc, but as long as it exists at all, I'm completely fine with that, I don't see why we make a big deal out of being separable, so please don't restrict yourself to that.

Comment: To your first comment : $y''=g(x)y$ is separable but -as the nice answer in your related question demonstrates- we cannot use that version of separability to find the solution of the ODE. To your second comment: whatever you do to make $t^2$ look different won't help, because again: see answer to first comment. To your third comment: how do you want to solve $\int\Gamma(y^{y'}-\log_y(y'))$ for $y$ ?

Comment: So what "version" of separable are you suggesting? I don't mind if we "can't" use that version, why would I? I showed $t^2$ can be written in terms of the second derivative, so my question is half-answered. I don't know how to integrate the gamma function, but the result is some other special function in terms of $y'$ and $y$ that must admit some functional inverse relationship that lets one solve for $y$ locally.

Comment: I suggest the "version" which we name after [Joseph Fourier (1768-1830)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) since more than two hundret years.